# How to add slide to swiper using AJAX?

Tags: javascript, swiper.js

I add a new slide through mainSlider.addSlide(1,[HTML slider]);

addSlide() - Swiper's method.
mainSlider - my slider;

But my added slide lies as if on top of the previous slide (screen):
[image]

Although below I run mainSlider.update(); - to update the slider.
But it does not work.

Code snippet:

```
export function mainSlider() {
  var mainSlider;
  if (window.outerWidth >= 960) {
    mainSlider = new Swiper('.section-slider', {
      ...
  } else {
    mainSlider = new Swiper('.section-slider', {
      ...
    });
  }

  var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
  request.open('GET', `https://www.omdbapi.com?s=run&apikey=daee70b3`, true);
  request.onload = function () {
    if (request.status >= 200 && request.status < 400) {
      var data = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
      dataParse(data);
    } else {
      alert('Maybe I was wrong');
    }
  };
  request.send();

  function dataParse(data) {
    mainSlider.addSlide(1, [
      `<li class="swiper-slide">
           ...
           ` + data.Search[0].Poster + `
           ...
       </li>`
    ]);
  }

  mainSlider.update();
  return mainSlider;
}
```

Well, in main.js my script file is imported.
No console errors.
How to solve the slider resize problem?

Comment: Your code looks fine (https://codepen.io/invalidusername/pen/GVQBoY) so it is probably a CSS issue. Maybe fork that pen and add some of your CSS. After the slide has been added, what does the DOM look like?

Comment: I copied the HTML from the DOM after adding the slide:

https://pastebin.com/ShBXB2Vj


CSS: https://pastebin.com/14G3rJPs


I would completely reproduce my slider in codepen.io but this is a bit difficult due to the large abundance of included files

Comment: The HTML looks fine. Can you share the CSS for your swiper-slide

Comment: Yes: https://pastebin.com/14G3rJPs

Comment: It was necessary to indicate **autoHeight: true**

Comment: Thanks for letting me know!